# Problems with recursive function

Tags: python, pandas, recursion, logic

what's up?

I have a json file like this:

```
{
"path": "path",
"children": [
    {   "path": "path/subPath1",
        "children": [
        {
            "path": "path/subPath1/subSubPath1",
            "mediums": [
                {
                    "medium": "midia1",
                    "platforms": [
                        1
                    ],
                    "platformsInfo": [
                        {
                            "platformId": 1,
                            "elegible": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "path/subPath1/subSubPath2",
            "mediums": [
                {
                    "medium": "midia2",
                    "platforms": [
                        2
                    ],
                    "platformsInfo": [
                        {
                            "platformId": 2,
                            "elegible": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "path": "path/subPath1/subSubPath3",
            "mediums": [
                {
                    "medium": "midia3",
                    "platforms": [
                        3
                    ],
                    "platformsInfo": [
                        {
                            "platformId": 3,
                            "elegible": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "path": "path/subPath2",
        "mediums": [
            {
                "medium": "midia4",
                "platforms": [
                    4
                ],
                "platformsInfo": [
                    {
                        "platformId": 4,
                        "elegible": false
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

And I wish a pd.DataFrame like this:

```
Path                                Medium          IdPlatform      Eligible
path/subPath1/subSubPath1           medium1         1               True
path/subPath1/subSubPath2           medium2         2               False
path/subPath1/subSubPath3           medium3         3               False
path/subPath2                       medium4         4               True
```

This json structure is mutable therefore I don't know how many levels and sublevels will have my object. However, I know the level that I want to return has the key "mediums" with a array of the mediums and the complete path. So, I imagine the better solution is a recursive function but I spent a couple of hours in this problem and I couldn't get anything.

Does anyone have a ideia or a better way to do this?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Hi @quamrana. Thanks for your comment, but I have really get nowhere so I've erased my code and if I get something I will update!

Comment: Which questions on stackoverflow are similar to yours?

Comment: I guess my structure complex and particular. If you find a similar stack questions that can help me, fell free to indicate. Any help with respect is welcome!

Comment: That's not how it works. My question was for you to answer with the results from *your* search.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
targets = ['path', 'medium', 'platformId', 'elegible']
def get_vals(d, k = {}):
  if isinstance(d, list):
     for i in filter(lambda x:isinstance(x, (dict, list)), d):
        yield from get_vals(i, k)
  else:
     k, flag = {**k, **{i:d.get(i) for i in targets if i in d}}, False
     for b in d.values():
        if isinstance(b, (list, dict)):
          flag = True
          yield from get_vals(b, k)
     if not flag:
        yield k
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list(get_vals(your_data)))
```

Output:

```
                        path  medium  platformId  elegible
0  path/subPath1/subSubPath1  midia1           1      True
1  path/subPath1/subSubPath2  midia2           2     False
2  path/subPath1/subSubPath3  midia3           3     False
3              path/subPath2  midia4           4     False
```